# Network Packet Sniffer:Process an Ethernet frame (MAC src&dest address + protocole) using python

Tags: python, process, protocols, ethernet, osi

I am trying to simply get and process my ethernet frame in python to do it i wrotte this simple code in python (helped by a tutorial):

```
import socket
import struct


def ethernet_frame_fct(data):
    dest_mac, src_mac, proto = struct.unpack('! 6s 6s H', data[:14])
    return get_mac_addr_fct(dest_mac), get_mac_addr_fct(src_mac), socket.htons(proto), data[14:]


def get_mac_addr_fct(bytes_addr):
    bytes_str = map('{:02x}'.format, bytes_addr)
    mac_addr = ':'.join(bytes_str).upper()
    return mac_addr


def main_fct():

    # if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
    #     conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCKET_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))
    # if platform == "win32":
    HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())  # the public network interface
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_IP)  # create a raw socket and bind it to the public interface
    conn.bind((HOST, 0))
    conn.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)  # Include IP headers
    conn.ioctl(socket.SIO_RCVALL, socket.RCVALL_ON)  # receives all packets

    while True:
        raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65536)

        dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame_fct(raw_data)
        print("\n-Ethernet Frame:")
        print('\t' + "MAC addr Destination= {}, MAC addr Source= {}, Protocol= {}".format(dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto))


#
main_fct()
```

The proble is that i get those results when i am running the program:
[image]

But the Source MAC address that should be MY mac address is not at all my MAC ADDRESS and the Protocole is not the one of an expected tag.
For exemple: 6=TCP, 17=UDP ...etc... but 17796 is not at all a value that i expected to get.
Concerning this last value for times to times i get different value as i run this programm on my laptot (so the wifi changes) but I NEVER got something logic.

As the usual ethernet frame should look like this:
[image]

I absolutely don't know where i am wrong.
For days i am really confused and stuck on this problem and so i will very appreciate if someone will be able to help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Somebody to help me?

Comment: no one can help me?

Comment: Still nobody can answer me and explain me where i am wrong?

Comment: Still nobody can help me? i am really stuck

Comment: still nobody to help?

Comment: Still anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Linux and the following code based entirely on your code works for me if run as root:

```py
import socket

ETH_P_ALL = 3
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL))
s.bind(('wlp4s0', 0))  # your WiFi interface, on Linux found using `ifconfig` or similar

eth_packet = s.recv(2048)  # get a sample packet
ethernet_frame_fct(eth_packet)
```

This gives me the correct MAC address of my WiFi card. The EtherType (proto) in my sample `eth_packet` should have been `ETH_P_IP` (IPv4 packet) which is [defined](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/169e77764adc041b1dacba84ea90516a895d43b2/include/uapi/linux/if_ether.h#L52) as `0x0800`, but I got `8` instead. So it seems you can remove the `socket.htons()` call to get the correct value.

Comment: Thank for your answer, i am going to try your code asap, but i am on windows, not linux

Comment: Your solution doesn't work at least on windows. For exemple whan i change recvfrom(65536) to recv(2048) i get the error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"